# How to implement scrollsToTop which is provided iOS to Android ListFragment

Tags: android

I create Application which uses `ListFragment`.

so, I want to scroll to top when `touch StatusBar`, like `UItableView` in iOS.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a OnClickListener to the StatusBar and use the scrollTo/smoothScrollTo methods of the listview.

Something like this

`getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(0);`

should help.